# Same JSESSIONID but different Session Object

Tags: java, session, servlets, nginx, tomcat7

I have an Java Http Servlet and trying to store things into the session. I have checked the request header and the same JSESSIONID is being sent each request.

However, every time, the session object (id) is different AND it contains none of the properties that we set in the last request.

More details: This works fine with just Tomcat7, but when I try to use nginx as a frontloader, the cookie is still sent, but the session object is still different.

Looks like the request URL is a fully-qualified domain.

Any ideas on what would be causing this or how to debug?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to check the proxy reverse config.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20623099/http-session-couldnt-hold-in-tomcat-and-nginx-proxypass-using-spring-mvc

Comment: Do you forward the host header?

Comment: When using nginx the header looks the same--the JSESSION id is in the cookie when it hits the servlet, as well as all the other cookie names

Comment: @user987339, that seems to have fixed it! Thanks!